# Can Iphone Apps change std. sms app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to make an App for the Iphone that apply changes to the Original Iphone SMS app?

for instance add a new button or play an animation when an sms is sent?

Answer (score 2):

Not in any way that's supported by Apple. It's likely to be possible if your phone is jailbroken, but other than that you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

No, apps are sandboxed so they can't access other apps on the phone unless there is support in the SDK for it (like accessing the camera roll or calendar).  You can do it with a jailbroken device though.